# Rigorous proof that $\sqrt{z}$ has a branch point at zero.

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, branch-points

Here is the definitions I am working with

[image]

Define the  map $$ (z-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ defined as the inverse of $$\begin{align} f: \mathbb{C} & \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \\ z &\mapsto z^{2}+1 \end{align}$$.

---

Establishing multivalues is immediate from the fact that $1$ and $-1$ get mapped to the same value by $f$.

To establish that $1$ is a branch point I think I should go about contradiction.

Suppose not. Then, by definition, there exists $\epsilon> 0$ such that there is a branch of the inverse map $g$ defined on the disk $D(1,\epsilon)$ with the point $1$ omitted. Now consider the contour
\begin{align*}
\gamma(t) = 1 + \frac{\epsilon}{2} e^{it}, \quad 0\leq t \leq 2\pi.
\end{align*}
Then I had the idea to show
\begin{align*}
\int_{\gamma }^{} g(z) \, \mathrm{d}z \neq  0. 
\end{align*}
This proved hard because I can't find an expression for
\begin{align*}
g(r e^{i\theta })
\end{align*}
to integrate. I also thought about defining $g$ in terms of its derivative but this was to no avail as
\begin{align*}
 f' (g(z)) g'(z) = 1 \implies g'(z) = \frac{1}{f' (g(z))}= \frac{1}{2 g(z)}.
\end{align*}
This removes any hopes to define the function as an integral.

**Question:** Formally how do I show that the square root function has a branch point at $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A branch point is defined by the fact there is no continuous instance of the function on a (small) circle around it - as continuity implies analyticity here (assuming of course the function is multivalued analytic to start with except at singularities); in this case assume there is a continuous hence analytic $f(z)^2=z$ on the circle of radius $1$ say around zero; one can use the argument principle and integrate $2f'/f=1/z$ on the circle giving that an even integer is equal to an odd integer which is a contradiction, but one can also argue from continuity only as follows:

$f(1)=\pm 1$ so wlog we can assume $f(1)=1$ by changing $f \to -f$ and then $f(-1)=\pm i$ so $\Re f(-1)=0$ and $-1$ is the only point on the circle with that property; hence $f$ continuous means $\Re f(z)>0, z \ne -1$ so in particular, we have $f(e^{i(\pi-\epsilon)})=e^{i(\pi-\epsilon)/2}$ since that is the positive real part square root, but then $f(e^{i(\pi+\epsilon)})=-e^{i(\pi+\epsilon)/2}$ since now that is the positive real part square root and taking $\epsilon \to 0$ gives a contradiction to continuity at $-1$

Comment: Hi, thank you for the quick answer. I have a question. Why do we get a contradiction with the argument principle? The function we have is bounded in this neighbourhood of the origin, and therefore the origin must be a removable singularity. Therefore the argument principle gives $2\pi i$ since we have only a zero contributing. This is the same as the the direct integral. What is wrong with that?

Comment: the relation is $2f'/f=1/z$ so doing $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C 2f'dz/f$ gives on the LHS an even integer (since by analyticity already  $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C f'dz/f$ is integral) and on the right-hand side $1$

Comment: ohh I see. thank you very much. I appreciate that you presented two ways of looking at this. I will accept your answer now.

Comment: happy to be of help - in general, the argument principle is the way to go for this type of problems but sometimes just looking at explicit computations is more illuminating in simple cases when those are available